# Create Custom Input

Tags: react-admin

I need create a custom input fot imagem , but don`t send value for my api

When I try create custom input, it show and work but don`t send a value

```js
import React  from 'react';

class InputImage extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    this.state = {
        src: ''
      };

      this._handleImageChange = this._handleImageChange.bind(this);

    }

   _handleImageChange =  (e) => {
  const file  = e.target.files[0];

        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = () => {
           this.setState({src:reader.result})
        };
   reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      }

      render(){
      return (
          <>
        <input source={this.props.source} type="hidden" value={this.state.src}  />

    <input type="file" onChange={this._handleImageChange} />
        </>
      )
      }
}

export default InputImage;
```